# Fill DataGrid From Text Box VB.net

Tags: vb.net

So I want to create student data,
I created form1 to fill in data using a `text box` and form2 to display data using `DataGridview`.
But my data is not displayed or empty.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        StudentData.Database.Rows.Add(1)
        StudentData.Database.Rows(Database.Length - 2).Cells(0).Value = txtName.Text 
        StudentData.Database.Rows(Database.Length - 2).Cells(1).Value = txtID.Text
        StudentData.Database.Rows(Database.Length - 2).Cells(2).Value = txtUniv.Text
        StudentData.Database.Rows(Database.Length - 2).Cells(3).Value = txtMajor.Text
        StudentData.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: You're setting the `ToolTipText`, which won't be visible unless you hover on something and a ToolTip is visible.  Was that your intention?  Another possible problem is that you're referencing Form2 via the default instance with `Form2`, while your actual Form2 instance might be different if you created an instance with the `New` keyword and displayed that instead.

Comment: I've edited it, but a popup appears "Use the 'new' keyword to create an object instance"

Comment: The popup appears and flags WHAT exactly?  I assume `StudentData.Database` is a SHARED member?...that was hopefully instantiated earlier somehow?

Comment: Here `StudentData.Database.Rows(Database.Length - 2).Cells(0).Value = txtName.Text`

Comment: So most likely you haven't yet create "Database" in `StudentData.Database`.  Show how that is declared and initialized.

Comment: Can u give an example, please? Where do I create "Database"

Comment: Show your `StudentData` class....

Comment: My `StudentData` form `DataGridView` only or do I have to show all the code form1?

Comment: Your code is accessing `StudentData.Database`, which is NOT the same as `StudentData.DataGridView`...

Comment: So is `StudentData` declared at Class/Form level?...or is that the name of the Class and `Database` would then presumably be a SHARED member?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, so I created form1 which contains a text box. and I created a StudentDataform which contains a DataGridView which I named "Database". What I want is when we fill in the data in form1, the data goes to StudentDataform

Comment: Great.  So "StudentData" is a FORM.  When you displayed that `StudentData` form, did you use the "new" keyword with it to create an instance and display it?

Comment: I've finished it, thank you very much for your help,